# nslookup does not resolve Kubernetes.default

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, kube-dns

I tried the following command on my minikube setup to verify if dns is working fine or not.

`kubectl exec -ti busybox -- nslookup kubernetes.default`

but this is the output I am getting
'
    Server:    10.96.0.10
    Address 1: 10.96.0.10

```
nslookup: can't resolve 'kubernetes.default'
command terminated with exit code 1'
```

Apart from that, I checked the coredns pod logs it shows something like below:
`
2019-11-07T12:25:23.694Z [ERROR] plugin/errors: 0 
    5606995447546819070.2414697521008405831. HINFO: read udp 172.17.0.5:60961-

> 10.15.102.11:53: i/o timeout
>   `

Can some explain me what is going wrong? busybox image tag is 
`image: busybox:1.28`

Answer (score 1):

Thats because your busybox pod know nothing about `kubernetes.default`
Fix your /etc/resolv.conf

It should be like

```
search default.svc.cluster.local svc.cluster.local
nameserver 10.96.0.10
options ndots:5
```

Additionally you cat open [Debugging DNS Resolution](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-debugging-resolution/) documentation and  check provided examle for the same.

> Take a look inside the resolv.conf file. (See Inheriting DNS from the
>   node and Known issues below for more information)

```
kubectl exec busybox cat /etc/resolv.conf
```

> Verify that the search path and name server are set up like the
>   following (note that search path may vary for different cloud
>   providers):

```
search default.svc.cluster.local svc.cluster.local cluster.local google.internal c.gce_project_id.internal
nameserver 10.0.0.10
options ndots:5
```

> Errors such as the following indicate a problem with the
>   coredns/kube-dns add-on or associated Services:

```
kubectl exec -ti busybox -- nslookup kubernetes.default
Server:    10.0.0.10
Address 1: 10.0.0.10

nslookup: can't resolve 'kubernetes.default'
or

kubectl exec -ti busybox -- nslookup kubernetes.default
Server:    10.0.0.10
Address 1: 10.0.0.10 kube-dns.kube-system.svc.cluster.local

nslookup: can't resolve 'kubernetes.default'
```

Comment: How can you state `Fix your /etc/resolv.conf` without even knowing the actual OP `/etc/resolv.conf` file? Also, the `nameserver` that you suggested apparently diverges from the Cluster DNS IP used in the OP installation (`10.96.0.10`).

Comment: ok, agree, changed nameserver(hohowever it should be clear for OP he should adopt for his infra). Most probably this is /etc/resolv.conf