# Visual studio docker container capable of seeing kubernetes pods outside?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, visual-studio-2019

I am currently developing docker containers using visual studio, and these container images are supposed to run in a kubernetes cluster that I am also running locally.

Currently, the docker container that is running via visual studio is not being deployed to a kubernetes cluster, but for some reason am I able to ping the kubernetes pod's ip address from the docker container, but for which I don't quite understand; should they not be separated, and not be able to reach each other?

- And it cannot be located on the kubernetes dashboard?
- And since they are connected, why can't I use the kubernetes service to connect to my pod from my docker container?

The docker container is capable of pinging the cluster IP, meaning that it is reachable.

nslookup the service is not able to resolve the hostname.

Comment: can you specify you current configuration? os, how you  created kubernetes cluster? Isnt it Docker for windows?  When Docker is installed, a default bridge network named  docker0 is created. Each new Docker container is automatically attached to this network, unless a custom network is specified.
Besides  docker0  , two other networks get created automatically by Docker:  host  (no isolation between host and containers on this network, to the outside world they are on the same network. Thats why you are able to reach your containers that are not in the cluster, but running under the same net

Comment: ahh.. cool that makes sense? But what would also mean that I sould be able to resolve the kubernetes services an ping "my service" which I cannot?

Answer (score 0):

So, as I already stated in the comment:

> When Docker is installed, a default bridge network named  docker0 is
>   created. Each new Docker container is automatically attached to this
>   network, unless a custom network is specified.

Thats mean you are able to ping containers by their respective IP. But you are not able to resolve DNS names of cluster objects - you VM know nothing about internal cluster DNS server.

Few option what you can do:

1) explicitly add record of cluster DNS to `/etc/hosts` inside VM

2) add a record to `/etc/resolv.conf` with `nameserver` and `search` inside VM. See one of my answers related to   DNS resolution on stack: [nslookup does not resolve Kubernetes.default](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58750566/9929015)

3)use [dnsmasq](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/doc.html) as described in [Configuring your Linux host to resolve a local Kubernetes cluster’s service URLs](https://blog.heptio.com/configuring-your-linux-host-to-resolve-a-local-kubernetes-clusters-service-urls-a8c7bdb212a7) article. Btw I highly recommend you read it from the beginning till the end. It greatly describes how to work with DNS  and what workaround you can use.

Hope it helps.